# listening comprehension of a movie trailer (Der Junge muss an die frische Luft)

Tags: listening-comprehension

I'm sorry I tried to listen to what the actors/actresses say in a movie trailer but it's too hard for me yet.
In this movie trailer, could any one please tell me what they are saying?
If not the whole clip, just a few statements until the first 35 seconds will suffice to me.
I'm in an internet band of people learning German in Korea and want to tell them what the statements are.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aviRQAyG-A

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have picked a trailer that might be challenging for beginners, since people do not have a very clear pronunciation and swallow endings. Furthermore, the dialect is influenced by Low German, where [some sounds are different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_German#Sound_change) than in High German.  I will try to transcribe what I hear in the first 35 seconds and add in brackets the standard German version to enable you to look up the words in dictionaries.

It starts relatively easy:

> boy: Einen wunderschönen guten Abend, meine Damen und Herren! Hallo Freunde!
>
> boy: Ich wär' dann soweit. (*wäre*)

IMHO, it gets more difficult here

> kid: Ich gewinn' schon wieder. (*gewinne*)
> woman: Hans-Peter, willste 'n Pferd? (*willst Du ein*)
> boy: Was?
> woman: Ob du 'n Pferd willst? (*ein*)
> boy: Ja!
>
> woman: Wennde weißt, watte willst, Hans-Peter, dann machet einfach! Kümmer' dich nich' dadrum, wat die Leute sagen. (*Wenn du weißt, was du willst, Hans-Peter, dann mach es einfach! Kümmere dich nicht darum, was die Leute sagen.*)
>
> boy: Jetz' schau'n 'se sich dat mal an! Hier kommte 'se: Die schwebende Jungfrau aus Wuppertal! (*Jetzt schauen sie sich das mal an! Hier kommt sie:*)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. A couple of us were just trying it for fun but was too hard. and I learned some photic effects ('s' sounds like 't' like in 'was->wat'). Again, thanks!